# Spring boot - set one entity to list in another entity. ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities Product and Tag. The relationship between them is ManyToMany, so one product can have multiple tags and one tag can be assigned to multiple products. The way the application works is that Product and Tag are created first and then assigned through PutMapping.

So my question is how can I assign Product to the List of Products in Tag Entity?

Entities:

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String productName;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Tag> tag;
}

public class Tag{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String tagName;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Product> product;
}
```

And methods that assign Product to the List in Tag and updates it, but this doesnt work.
First Im trying to find the existing Tag and Product and then set the product to the List in Tag entity.

```
public Tag update(Long productID, Long tagID, Tag tag){

 Tag udpatedTag = tagRepository.findById(tagID).get();
 Product product = productRepository.findById(productID).get();

 updatedTag.setProduct((List <Product>) product);
 tagRepository.save(updatedTag)

 return updatedTag;
}
```

Comment: *but this doesnt work* is not an error description. Do you get any error? `tagRepository.save(updatedTag)` should return the updated object. So try `return tagRepository.save(updatedTag)`

Comment: You are also casting a `Product` to a `List<Product>` why?

Comment: Reconsider the logic of your method. if you're trying to add a product to the tag, or a tag to the product, consider changing the method name to addProduct, addTag. If you're updating the entire entity, consider using a list as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You want to ADD the product to the list, not cast the `Product` to a `List`.  Also, consider renaming your `product` variable in `Tag` to `products` because it is a `Collection` of `Product`.  Also, you should consider using a `Set` for your `ManyToMany` mappings.  Dig around on the interwebs to understand the differences of `List` vs `Set` for `OneToMany` and `ManyToMany` mappings.

```
public Tag update(Long productID, Long tagID, Tag tag){

  Tag udpatedTag = tagRepository.findById(tagID).get();
  Product product = productRepository.findById(productID).get();

  // Get the Collection and add the product to it
  updatedTag.getProduct().add(product);
  tagRepository.save(updatedTag)

  return updatedTag;
}
```

Comment: So I used this and right now Im getting empty list. Before I got "product": null, and now "product": []. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use many to many structures, you need to create a separate table.

For example ;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqS6v.jpg)

You can check this site -> https://www.bezkoder.com/jpa-many-to-many/

Answer (score 0):

As Iane.maxwell suggested its better if you create a seperate tablelike this :

Product 1---M Product_Tag M----1 Tag

So that you have control of that table. But if you want to use @ManyToMany annotation don't forget to use mappedBy inside the annotation or it will create 2 tables i.e product_tag and tag_product.

I did what Iane.maxwell suggested and I got the output like this :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tagName": "tag-1",
    "product": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "productName": "product-1",
            "tag": []
        }
    ]
}
```